# C++ OpenGL stb_image.h errors

Tags: c++, opengl, stb-image

I am following an OpenGL tutorial from https://learnopengl.com/ (specifically https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing) and I have many errors to do with stbi. [Error Log image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsZYD.png) (Below I have also attached the complete Output tab). I have added the "#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION" at the top of the main.cpp file (and not in a header). If I don't use any stb_image functionalities, the project compiles and runs. I have had projects where stb_image worked fine, but all those projects that worked were x86 (or 32-bit). It seems that I can not get stb_image with x64 (or 64-bit). I know that x64 itself works since other projects without stb_image that were x64 have compiled. I have also looked back to where I downloaded the header file for stb_image and there was no option for x64 vs x86 as there was only one universal option. Here is an image of how the files are organized: [File hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45FpM.png). I will also include my main.cpp file but if you want to see a specific file let me know. I am very new to c++ since I come from java and python so any help is appreciated.

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stb_image.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <Shader.h>
#include <Camera.h>
#include <Model.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);
unsigned int loadTexture(const char* path);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

// camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
float lastX = (float)SCR_WIDTH / 2.0;
float lastY = (float)SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0;
bool firstMouse = true;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f;
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    // tell GLFW to capture our mouse
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // configure global opengl state
    // -----------------------------
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS); // always pass the depth test (same effect as glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST))

    // build and compile shaders
    // -------------------------
    Shader shader("depth_testing.vs", "depth_testing.fs");

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float cubeVertices[] = {
        // positions          // texture Coords
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    float planeVertices[] = {
        // positions          // texture Coords (note we set these higher than 1 (together with GL_REPEAT as texture wrapping mode). this will cause the floor texture to repeat)
         5.0f, -0.5f,  5.0f,  2.0f, 0.0f,
        -5.0f, -0.5f,  5.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -5.0f, -0.5f, -5.0f,  0.0f, 2.0f,

         5.0f, -0.5f,  5.0f,  2.0f, 0.0f,
        -5.0f, -0.5f, -5.0f,  0.0f, 2.0f,
         5.0f, -0.5f, -5.0f,  2.0f, 2.0f
    };
    // cube VAO
    unsigned int cubeVAO, cubeVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeVertices), &cubeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    // plane VAO
    unsigned int planeVAO, planeVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &planeVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &planeVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, planeVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(planeVertices), &planeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // load textures
    // -------------
    unsigned int cubeTexture = loadTexture("resources/textures/container.jpg");
    unsigned int floorTexture = loadTexture("resources/textures/awesomeface.png");

    // shader configuration
    // --------------------
    shader.use();
    shader.setInt("texture1", 0);

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // per-frame time logic
        // --------------------
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        shader.use();
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        shader.setMat4("view", view);
        shader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        // cubes
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
        shader.setMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        shader.setMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        // floor
        glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, floorTexture);
        shader.setMat4("model", glm::mat4(1.0f));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &planeVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &planeVBO);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(UP, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT_CONTROL) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(DOWN, deltaTime);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse moves, this callback is called
// -------------------------------------------------------
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; // reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to top

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse scroll wheel scrolls, this callback is called
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}

// utility function for loading a 2D texture from file
// ---------------------------------------------------
unsigned int loadTexture(char const* path)
{
    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    int width, height, nrComponents;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 1)
            format = GL_RED;
        else if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        stbi_image_free(data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Texture failed to load at path: " << path << std::endl;
        stbi_image_free(data);
    }

    return textureID;
}
```

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: DepthTesting, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\Shader.h(56,40): warning C4101: 'e': unreferenced local variable
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(677,12): error C2084: function 'int stbi__cpuid3(void)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(677): message : see previous definition of 'stbi__cpuid3'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(699,12): error C2084: function 'int stbi__sse2_available(void)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(699): message : see previous definition of 'stbi__sse2_available'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(701,17): error C2065: 'stbi__cpuid3': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(701,31): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'int'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(701,15): message : There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(762,3): error C2371: 'stbi__context': redefinition; different basic types
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(762): message : see declaration of 'stbi__context'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(768,13): error C2084: function 'void stbi__start_mem(stbi__context *,const stbi_uc *,int)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(768): message : see previous definition of 'stbi__start_mem'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(778,13): error C2084: function 'void stbi__start_callbacks(stbi__context *,stbi_io_callbacks *,void *)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(778): message : see previous definition of 'stbi__start_callbacks'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(792,12): error C2084: function 'int stbi__stdio_read(void *,char *,int)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(792): message : see previous definition of 'stbi__stdio_read'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(797,13): error C2084: function 'void stbi__stdio_skip(void *,int)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(797): message : see previous definition of 'stbi__stdio_skip'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(807,12): error C2084: function 'int stbi__stdio_eof(void *)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(807): message : see previous definition of 'stbi__stdio_eof'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(812,26): error C2374: 'stbi__stdio_callbacks': redefinition; multiple initialization
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(812): message : see declaration of 'stbi__stdio_callbacks'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(819,13): error C2084: function 'void stbi__start_file(stbi__context *,FILE *)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(819): message : see previous definition of 'stbi__start_file'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(821,5): error C2065: 'stbi__start_callbacks': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(828,13): error C2084: function 'void stbi__rewind(stbi__context *)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(828): message : see previous definition of 'stbi__rewind'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(839,5): error C2365: 'STBI_ORDER_RGB': redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
...
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1286,13): message : There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1288,20): error C2065: 'stbi__err': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1294,18): error C2084: function 'stbi_uc *stbi_load_from_file(FILE *,int *,int *,int *,int)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1294): message : see previous definition of 'stbi_load_from_file'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1298,5): error C2065: 'stbi__start_file': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1299,14): error C2065: 'stbi__load_and_postprocess_8bit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1299,71): error C2568: '=': unable to resolve function overload
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1299,71): message : could be 'unsigned char *stbi__load_and_postprocess_8bit(stbi__context *,int *,int *,int *,int)'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1307,23): error C2084: function 'stbi_us *stbi_load_from_file_16(FILE *,int *,int *,int *,int)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1307): message : see previous definition of 'stbi_load_from_file_16'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1311,5): error C2065: 'stbi__start_file': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1312,14): error C2065: 'stbi__load_and_postprocess_16bit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1312,72): error C2568: '=': unable to resolve function overload
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1312,72): message : could be 'stbi__uint16 *stbi__load_and_postprocess_16bit(stbi__context *,int *,int *,int *,int)'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1320,18): error C2084: function 'stbi_us *stbi_load_16(const char *,int *,int *,int *,int)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1320): message : see previous definition of 'stbi_load_16'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1322,15): error C2065: 'stbi__fopen': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1322,42): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'FILE *(__cdecl *)(const char *,const char *)' to 'FILE *'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1322,13): message : There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1324,30): error C2065: 'stbi__err': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1325,14): error C2065: 'stbi_load_from_file_16': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1325,61): error C2568: '=': unable to resolve function overload
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1325,61): message : could be 'stbi_us *stbi_load_from_file_16(FILE *,int *,int *,int *,int)'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1333,18): error C2084: function 'stbi_us *stbi_load_16_from_memory(const stbi_uc *,int,int *,int *,int *,int)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1333): message : see previous definition of 'stbi_load_16_from_memory'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1336,5): error C2065: 'stbi__start_mem': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1337,12): error C2065: 'stbi__load_and_postprocess_16bit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1340,18): error C2084: function 'stbi_us *stbi_load_16_from_callbacks(const stbi_io_callbacks *,void *,int *,int *,int *,int)' already has a body
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1340): message : see previous definition of 'stbi_load_16_from_callbacks'
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1343,5): error C2065: 'stbi__start_callbacks': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1344,12): error C2065: 'stbi__load_and_postprocess_16bit': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\caleb\Documents\OpenGL\AdvancedOpenGL\DepthTesting\include\stb_image.h(1344,89): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
1>Done building project "DepthTesting.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Recommendation: replace the image with text. Images shouldn't be used here because they are much harder to search and are blockers to too many users. Right beside the error list is the Output tab. The Output tab contains the complete build output in easily cut-n-pasteable text. Because it's the complete build output it contains more details and often hints about what should have been done instead.

Comment: Are your other headers like Shader, Camera, and Model also including stb_image.h? You need to define `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` after all of the other headers that include it and then include it to get the implementation only once. If you look at the example given in the file the define and include are last.

Comment: @RetiredNinja this solution worked perfectly I just moved the define and include for stb_image to be below the headers that also used stb_image. Thank you so much. I would upvote or make your answer the best answer but I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Retired Ninja in the comments, all you do to fix it is to put the #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION and #include stb_image.h after all the headers that also include the stb_image.h file. Once this was fixed, the program runs but I am getting a frame not found error but I think that is a separate issue from this.